# How to set Excel read only file/sheet by C# interop?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010, excel-interop

**I need to perform this operation by c# Excel Interop:**

**The step is:**

**File->Informations-> Authorizations -> Protect current sheet**

**Step 1:**
[image]

**Step 2: set true/false the follow check boxes and insert a Password for a current sheet**

[image]

I don't find any information to do it.

Comment: Most people here won't have an italian Excel. Please describe, what you want to do and what the steps you do manually. Please use english language

Comment: Done @RomanoZumbé

Answer (score 1):

My Italian is non-existant. If you are asking how to save an Excel workbook with a password, you are looking for the [Workbook.SaveAs documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) - should look something like this:

```
myWorkBook.SaveAs(myfilename, format, password)
```

**Edit** - To protect a specific sheet, use the [WorkSheet.Protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx) method.

Comment: This solution set a password to open file, I need to set Read Only with password.

Comment: @daniele3004 Edited answer. Note the `true`/`false` arguments required for the tickboxes.